# Convert datetime to protobuf Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

So I'm trying to prepare a message with Python that takes a Timestamp, but I'm having trouble converting a datetime to a protobuf Timestamp.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```py
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = Timestamp()
timestamp.FromDatetime(now)
```

However, I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object attribute 'seconds' is read-only`

How can I create a Timestamp from a datetime?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code is working fine on my machine

```
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = Timestamp()
timestamp.FromDatetime(now)
```

Output:

```
seconds: 1591859232
nanos: 803377000
```

Comment: Python Specs: Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32